# How to play sounds on android faster?

Tags: android, linux, performance, alsa

I'm working on adding a feature to the Android platform to play a sound from the speaker with the absolute lowest latency possible. I found `tinyplay.c` in the `tinyalsa` external project and I am using that as a model. I want to open the pcm device and play a sound and close it within 10 ms if possible.

Right now when I call `pcm_params_get` or `pcm_open` it will sometimes take only a few millis, but sometimes it takes up to 4 seconds! I believe that if an android sound has played recently it takes longer. If I open well in advance and then use `pcm_write` the audio plays very quickly, in just a couple millis. How can I guarantee a faster `pcm_open` time so I can get to playing sooner? Is there some method to force it to open faster in some way? I don't mind if I have to open it up to a couple hundred millis in advance, but 4 seconds is way too long.

I realize that while I have this open I am monopolizing the audio driver, that is totally fine. I just don't want to monopolize it forever.

**UPDATE**

I have modified AudioFlinger to not standby and that eliminated the `pcm_open` slowness. Now I am seeing a delay before sound comes out of the speaker when calling `pcm_write`:

```
01-23 06:01:29.728: PCM write 16384
01-23 06:01:29.742: PCM write 16384
01-23 06:01:29.832: PCM write 16384
01-23 06:01:29.925: PCM write 16384
01-23 06:01:30.017: PCM write 6280
```

Notice that the first `pcm_write` takes only 14ms, but others take ~90ms. From my measurements it seems that the first `pcm_write` is returning without the speaker actually emitting my sound. Why is that?

Comment: I think this line in AudioFlinger.h explains the approx 4 second delay: `static const nsecs_t kDefaultStandbyTimeInNsecs = seconds(3);` Most likely I need to tell AudioFlinger to stop immediately...

Comment: The device we are building doesn't need to be great for playing games, my best idea so far is to change that number to 300ms, that should ensure that is the maximum time I need to wait before open succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was two-fold:

1. This requires platform level permissions: Modify the `kDefaultStandbyTimeInNsecs` in the platform to a lower value. The platform source also mentions the property `ro.audio.flinger_standbytime_ms`.
2. Use the same sample rate as the platform: 48Khz