# How to prevent speaker pop when opening ALSA on android?

Tags: android, linux, alsa

This is closely related to my other ALSA on Android question: [How to play sounds on android faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205094/how-to-open-alsa-on-android-faster) This time the question is how to prevent the speaker from making a small popping sound when I call `pcm_open` in the tinypcm library to open up the ALSA driver? The pop doesn't happen 100% of the time but it does not sound good, and it also if I happen to be opening or closing the ALSA driver around the time that android is playing audio the android sound is bit corrupted.

Comment: What is the device you are using? What are the versions of Android and Linux kernel on it?

Comment: Tegra 114 based board, Android 4.4.2, Linux kernel 3.4.66. This is a special purpose built device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. The problem was I was not using exact same configuration when opening the audio driver as android, the sample rate android uses is 48Khz, I was using 44.1Khz. Now there is no speaker pop.